# Reraising an exception as an HTTP error in Pyramid

Tags: python, http, pyramid, wsgi

I have a web app in python Pyramid which calls various other code in python which may raise an exception. 
Instead of the user receiving a "500 Internal Error", I'd like them to get a more specific error, for instance if *MyException* is thrown, show a 503 Error. I tried to do this:

```
@view_config(context=MyException, permission='view')
def custom_exc(exc, request):
   raise HTTPServiceUnavailable(exc.message)
```

However, that fails because it is for some reason unauthorized:

```
HTTPForbidden: Unauthorized: custom_exc failed permission check
```

My ACL is as follows:

```
class RootFactory(object):
    __acl__ = [
        (Allow, 'admin', ('view',))
        ]
```

I am connected with the user *admin* and it works perfectly for other views.

Does anyone know how to solve this or else how to "chain" exceptions in Pyramid in a different way?

Comment: Have you taken a look at Pyramid's [exception views](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid-cookbook/en/latest/pylons/exceptions.html)? I've used those for capturing and returning specific errors, although I haven't run into authorization errors in doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Learn from a [customized version of famous ToDoPyramid example application](https://github.com/saschagottfried/todopyramid/blob/master/todopyramid/views.py#L32). This way I translate an internal technical event, a database exception, into a meaningful application specific message within custom exception view code. Some guys call this a layer of abstraction or information hiding.

Do not protect these exception views with permissions, since you should protect code that does stuff and CAN raise exceptions.

```
from sqlalchemy.exc import OperationalError as SqlAlchemyOperationalError

@view_config(context=SqlAlchemyOperationalError)
def failed_sqlalchemy(exception, request):
    """catch missing database, logout and redirect to homepage, add flash message with error
    implementation inspired by pylons group message
    https://groups.google.com/d/msg/pylons-discuss/BUtbPrXizP4/0JhqB2MuoL4J
    """

    msg = 'There was an error connecting to database'
    request.session.flash(msg, queue='error')
    headers = forget(request)
    # Send the user back home, everything else is protected
    return HTTPFound(request.route_url('home'), headers=headers)
```